# how to display all type of files inline of aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some uploaded files it will be .docx or .xl or .Png or .PDF and so on... some of the file types like PDF and .GIF are opening Inline of the aspx pages and if it is document file it is opening in  word document..if it is exel file it is opening in exel ..i want do display all the types in line

Comment: well if you go to adobe reader `Preferences` -> under `Internet` you can enable/disable **Display in browser** (no such option under word, excel as i know of)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible or not , but you can try setting "content-disposition "on response header in order to open files in-place, .

```
content-disposition :inline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with this:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.ext")
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether a document or file renders in the browser or in a separate program depends on whether there is a browser plugin installed that is capable of rendering that type of document, or whether the browser can natively render that type of document.